# Asp .net core WebApi to return Foreign key Id as value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

net 
Here I'm working on Asp .net core using Entity Framework Core(version 3.1.2) and i'm using ***mssql*** server as my DB

**i have two entity class Region and country**

**Region.cs**

```
[Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(20)")]
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "Bit")]
    [Required]
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
```

**Country.cs**

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Code { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
[Required]
public string Description { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "Bit")]
[Required]
public Boolean Active { get; set; }
[Required]
public int RegionId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("RegionId")]
public virtual Region Region { get; set;}
```

And my **Db context**

```
    public class MasterContext: DbContext
  {
    public MasterContext(DbContextOptions options):  base(options)
    {}
    public DbSet<Region> regions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<country> countries { get; set; }
  }
```

and my **startup.cs**

```
services.AddMvc()
           .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
           .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
             var resolver = options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
             if (resolver != null)
               (resolver as DefaultContractResolver).NamingStrategy = null;
           });
  services.AddControllers();
  services.AddDbContext<MasterContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dev")));

    }
```

**connection String** in *appsettings.json*

```
**"ConnectionStrings": {
"dev": "Server=ADMIN;Database=MASTERS;User Id=vibe;Password=vibe"
```

}

**country controller**

```
// GET: api/countries/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<country>> Getcountry(int id)
        {
            var country = await _context.countries.Include(i => i.Region).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

            if (country == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return country;
        }
```

when i get the value by passing the Url(http://localhost:65177/api/regions/10) in the postman tool
it *returns* value like this

**what i get**

```
    {
    "Id":10,
    "Code":"inn",
    "Description":"india",
    "Active":true,
    "RegionId":5,
    "Region": {
    "Id":5,
    "Code":"me",
    "Description":"middle east",
    "Active":true
}
    }
```

And what i'm expecting is this

```
{
"Id":10,
"Code":"inn",
"Description":"india",
"Active":true,
"RegionId": {
"Id":5,
"Code":"me",
"Description":"middle east",
"Active":true
}
}
```

pls anyone give me a solution to solve this...thanks in advance.

Comment: Should `[ForeignKey("RegionId")]` be on the RegionId field and not the Region virtual?

Comment: I think the current behavior is perfectly correct. In your Country class, Region is an object, and RegionId is the string with the Id of the Region object. I don't understand why this json structure is not working for you. That said, you could try using attributes in Country class. [JsonIgnore] in RegionId property will prevent it from being serialized. [JsonProperty("RegionId")] in Region property will serialize it as "RegionId".

Comment: jsonignore  annotation block the property by cannot able to read and write,any other suggestion pls...,because i want perform crud operations in that

Answer (score 1):

Use json ignore attribute. For example, `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: where do i want to use that

Comment: @Lvibescreation in the Country.cs

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below attribute in your `Country` model(add a reference of `using Newtonsoft.Json;` firstly)

```
[Required]
[JsonIgnore]
public int RegionId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("RegionId")]
[JsonProperty("RegionId")]
public virtual Region Region { get; set;}
```